# How can I fix "invalid input syntax for type tid" in a Python script using pyodbc to query a PostgreSQL 9.5 table?

Tags: postgresql

I have a Python script running in Python 2.7 that uses the ADO library via COM to insert a record into a table in a PostgreSQL 9.5 database.  I am getting sporadic errors (maybe once in every 100 inserts) with the following message:

```
2021-09-07 02:32:24 - ERROR -  Failed to write upload data into status_upload table:
(-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', 
(0, u'Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers', u'ERROR: invalid input syntax for type tid:
"";ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xef 0x5e 0x27;\npositioned_load failed',
None, 0, -2147467259), None)
```

positioned_load is not a field in the status_upload table.

I thought it had something to do with the fact that updateable cursors were selected in the DSN I was using, so I turned them off.  I started getting errors from the ADORecordset.Update() call complaining that ADO couldn't find the record to update, so I replaced those calls with calls to ADODatabase.Execute() with an insert query built in the script.  But I'm still getting the tid errors.

I'm working on a replacement script that will run in Python 3.8 and use pyodbc, but I would still like to understand the tid errors.

Comment: My two cents, at the source, you have a file or table with an encoding different than utf8 (sql_Ascii, edb*, etc) and when you hit a char not compatible with utf8, crash the script. So, can you re-encode the source or re encode data to utf8 before run the insert?

Comment: Do you have access to the Postgres logs?  Under the error you should be able to see the offending `STATEMENT` that caused the error -- that might give some clues to what the Python script and/or the ODBC driver is doing